# Reregister device with Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

I was recently going through my list of devices on the web Play Store to remove an old device.  While looking at the list, I saw that I had two entries for my Nexus 4: "LG Google Nexus 4" and "Nexus 4".  As I installed CyanogenMod shortly after getting the phone, I wasn't surprised to see the second entry.  I decided to delete the one called "LG Google Nexus 4" as it was registered when I first got the phone.

Yesterday, I went to install an app to my phone using the web Play Store, but I no longer have any devices listed there.  I tried reselecting the account to use in the Play Store app, and also wiped data for the app using TitaniumBackup and relogging into the Play Store app.  Neither approach caused my device to be added back to the web Play Store device list.  How can I readd my Nexus 4 to the devices attached to my account?

Comment: Have you tried to just install some app (via the *Google Play* app)? That should trigger something there :)

Comment: I installed the new Google Keyboard app last night, but no dice.  Still no device listed on the web Play Store.

Comment: That's strange. I wonder if it would help to buy some app (and optionally use the 15min restore window to refund it), which is what helps when you're reloacating to another country (for apps with regional restrictions). But as for the device showing up, a simple install should suffice. I've got no more ideas but to contact the support then -- but maybe somebody else has another idea?

Comment: How did you remove your device from Play Store? I don't think there's an option on play.google.com

Comment: It might have been me deauthorizing the device for Google Music.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding each device listing in the Play Store is referenced to a Unique ID. By removing the device you have removed this ID. You should be able to sign out of your Google account on your device, then sign back in, making sure all of the sync features are turned on, this should create a new UID for your device, putting an entry in devices once again.